# How to maintain the list of VM in case free ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, powercli

In our company we do not have licensed ESXi. I am having 10 ESXi server and using Vsphere to connect each and every machine.

Whenever i am giving machine to users i store few information in excel like follows

```
IP_Address |VMName |GivenTo| Os| Host-credential|
```

In my Vsphere shortcut properties i have written a command

```
"C:\Program Files\VMware\Infrastructure\Virtual Infrastructure Client\Launcher\VpxClient.exe" -s <IPAddress> -u <rootusername> -p <Password>
```

Then i would add a hyperlink to that shortcut. Though this mechanism helps me to maintain my machines better. Still i think i can reach best.

Have you used any best practice to maintain multiple free ESXi server and keep tracking of users? Please share with me. I can adapt few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Buy vCenter. It's worth it.
2. Using PowerCLI you can connect to multiple ESXi hosts at the same time using the connect-viserver cmdlet (you might be asked if you want to enable this the first time).  Then you can run queries across all the ESXi hosts.